# Invalid conversion from `char*' to `char'

Tags: c

Всем доброго времени суток!

Недавно мы начали разбирать функции, и я пишу третью. И тут сталкиваюсь с ошибкой, которая указана в заголовке: `invalid conversion from 'char*' to 'char'` - эта ошибка указана в 16 строке.

Ещё одна ошибка: `invalid types 'char[int]' for array subscript` - на 27/28 строках.
Объясните подробно, почему я ошибаюсь, как избегать таких ошибок и как её исправить в моем случае.

---

В общем, что за функция search и что она дает: в функции есть Vocal[12] - это гласные, мы на вход получаем исходный массив текста и сравниваем каждую букву с нашими гласными, если гласные попались, мы садим их в результирующий массив, в нашем случае - это result[12].

---

И ещё вопрос, объясните, как объявлять функцию? В каких случаях перед функцией писать void, int, char?

Заранее спасибо за ответы! Буду очень благодарен!

---

Попробовал поставить везде void search (т.е. только в двух местах) и после аргументов поставил скобки [], заработало.
Покажу новый код, работает, но неправильно, по разному - то выводит гласные, то вообще пустая строка.

---

Всем спасибо, кто отписался!

---

Поправил код.

```
main(){
  char text[12];
  char result[12];
  int i;

  gets(text);

  i = strlen(text); //считаем и сажаем нулевой символ в последнюю ячейку
  text[i + 1] = 0;

  search(text, result); //ищем гласные

  getch();
}

void search(char text[], char result[]){
  char vocal[12] = {'A', 'a', 'E', 'e', 'O', 'o', 'Y', 'y', 'U', 'u', 'I', 'i'};
  int i, j, v = 0;

  for(j = 0; j < 11; j++){ // счётчик 1 символа text
    for(i = 0; i < 11; i++){ //сравниваем 1 символ с регистром
      if(text[j] == vocal[i]){ 
        result[v] = text[j];  
        v++;
      }
    }
  }

  printf("\nVocal words: %s", result);
}
```

Comment: @DrummerIF, для начала вспоминаем, что строка в си должна заканчиваться 0 и соответственно переписываем код. 

И хорошо бы всегда перед функцией писать комментарий, что она делает (так сказать цель, для чего ее вообще написали).

Например:

    // возвращает в аргументе result[] все гласные из text[]
    // необходимый размер result[] обеспечивает вызывающий код
    void search /* название дурацкое */ (....

Потом узнаем о наличии функции `toupper()` и атрибута `static`, со здоровым любопытством читаем о них и улучшаем код.

Задумываемся, а что бы еще сделатьать и возвращаем длину `result[]`.

Comment: Я описал, СПЕЦИАЛЬНО для всех ещё в начале своего вопроса, функцию.
А причем тут toupper? Он не здесь боком не нужен. Про атрибут статик нам ещё не говорили и не знаю что это такое.

Comment: @DrummerIF,  Вы правы. 

При подходе -- "нам еще не говорили", toupper (или tolower как и многое другое, связанное с обработкой символов) Вам действительно не нужна.

--

Однако, вопрос с нулями, терминирующими строки IMHO остается.

Comment: Ой, вот давайте без этого всего.
Ну, дак, объясните, пожалуйста, зачем тут toupper.

Comment: @DrummerIF, отвечать на удаленный комментарий довольно странно, но, ладно.

Безусловно, *практического* значения использование toupper в данном случае не имеет, поскольку мощность множества гласных мала. В принципе же, сравнение

     if (toupper(text[i]) == vocal[i]) ...

позволит уменьшить  размер массива vocal[] вдвое.

Объявление же

    static char vocal[] = { ... };

перенесет заполнение памяти со времени исполнения на время компиляции.

--

Что же касается нулей. 

Представьте, что Вы читаете строки в цикле. Что будет в result[] если после строки `aaaaaaaa` читается строка `bb`? И т.п.

Comment: Кстати, я поправил код выше. А что касаемо нулей? Я же посадил в последнюю ячейку нулевой символ, не понимаю вас. Там не должны оставаться другие символы из памяти.

Comment: @DrummerIF, откуда такие фантазии? И что там будет? 

(Кстати, вот прямо тот код, что у Вас сейчас, так он вообще неправильный. Память text[12] и result[12] не инициализирована, там могут быть любые символы, просто распечатайте коды:

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 12; i++)
       printf("0x%02x ", (unsigned char)text[i]);
    puts("");

)

А допустим, в начале там все `a` и Вы читаете строку `bc`. Получаете "bc\000aaaaaaaaa" и что будет после вызова `search()`?

Чем больше Вы сами себе задаете подобных вопросов и  проверяете догадки очевидными программами, тем быстрее научитесь писать.

Comment: Да, тут лимит комментариев -- 4 шт. Этот 5-й и последний. 

Если будут еще вопросы -- открывайте новую тему.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

писать нужно то, что функция возвращает. Судя по коду, она ничего не возвращает. Поэтому нужно писать void в начале.

А вот ругается оно потому, что параметры Вы передаете как строки, а функция ожидает символ. По коду она оперирует массивами символов (то есть, строками).

То есть, я бы делал объявление как минимум такое:

```
void search(char a[], char b[]);
```

И ещё. Вы пишите, что код на Си. Так зачем тогда подключаете плюсовые плюшки и компилируете плюсовым компилятором?

Comment: >потому, что у нас самый дурацкий учитель в мире

или ученики, что бывает гораздо чаще

> И ещё Dev-c++ он не только для плюсового, но и для сишного.

Dev C++ - это не компилятор, это IDE

Comment: компилятор в этой IDE не встроенный. Так что проблема не в преподавателе:)

Answer (score 1):

Несколько замечаний: не надо использовать gets, лучше fgets. Пример есть даже в Википедии.

Внутренний цикл совершенно бессмысленный, его можно заменить функцией strchr.

getch, видимо, используется для того, чтобы окошко не закрывалось. Лучше сразу учиться писать нормально, без таких вот "костылей", а программу запускать в командной строке.

В качестве компилятора рекомендую TinyCC. Он умеет запускать программу сразу, без компиляции, что очень удобно как раз для таких "лабораторок". А еще почитайте, что такое юнит-тестирование. Сразу отпадут многие вопросы и ошибки. Советую фреймворк [greatest](https://clck.ru/9FnzS).