# Самописная функция search (недовопросы)

Tags: c

Всем доброго времени суток, с кем не поприветствовался. Продолжение вопросом по предыдущей теме ->> [Invalid conversion from `char*' to `char'](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/395517/invalid-conversion-from-char-to-char)

Буду отталкиваться от предыдущей темы.

---

Размер строк **text** и **result** у меня стоит произвольный. С указателями я не работал и дальше будем учить. **Static** и **toupper** я применил к коду. Спасибо **avp**.

Что же касается остальных вопросов, по поводу цитат **avp**:

> Задумываемся, а что бы еще сделать и
>   возвращаем длину `result[]`.
>
> (Кстати, вот прямо тот код, что у Вас
>   сейчас, так он вообще неправильный.
>   Память 'text[12]' и 'result[12]' не
>   инициализирована, там могут быть любые
>   символы, просто распечатайте коды:
>
> ```
> int i;
>   for (i = 0; i < 12; i++)
>    printf("0x%02x ", (unsigned char)text[i]);
> puts("");
> ```
>
> )
>
> А допустим, в начале там все `a` и Вы
>   читаете строку `bc`. Получаете
>   "`bc\000aaaaaaaaa`" и что будет после
>   вызова `search()`?

---

Не понял по поводу возвращения длины `result[]`.

Не понял про инициализирование 'text[12]' и 'result[12]'

Не понял, что за код в цитате и что этот цикл делает, что за непонятные цифры `"0x%02x"` и словосочетание в начале аргументе `(unsigned char)text[i]`.

Не понял про '"bc\000aaaaaaaaa"'.

---

Код моей программы ниже и там же эта функция по нахождению гласных. Извиняюсь, если туго до меня доходит, но с горем пополам, пытаюсь понять, что и как работает. Заранее спасибо за ответы!

И вопрос по поводу, с какой функции вводить строку? fgets, gets или scanf?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

void search(char text[], char result[]);

void sorting(char result[]);

main(){
  char text[12];
  char result[12];
  int c;

  printf("This programm search vocal words and sorting their.\n\nInstruction:\n\n1. Enter simple text\n2. See result\n\nEnter simple text: ");

  fgets(text, 12, stdin);

  c = strlen(text); //считаем и сажаем в последнюю ячейку нулевой символ
  text[c + 1] = 0;

  search(text, result); //эта функция ищет гласные в text и сажает их в result

  getch();
}

void search(char text[], char result[]){
  static char vocal[6] = {'A', 'E', 'O', 'Y', 'U', 'I'}; //регистр гласных
  int i, j, c, v = 0;   

  c = strlen(text);

  for(j = 0; j < c; j++){ //сравниваем, начиная с первой буквой регистра
    for(i = 0; i < c; i++){ //сравниваем, начиная с первой буквы строки
      if(toupper(text[j]) == vocal[i]){ 
        result[v] = text[j];  
        v++;
      }
    }
  }

  printf("\nVocal words: %s", result);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[[@DrummerIF](/users/23380/drummerif)](/users/23380/drummerif), это замечательно, что Вы стараетесь.

По поводу текущего кода.

Писать `text[c + 1] = 0` не только излишне, но и опасно. Излишне, поскольку (читаем [man fgets](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets)) fgets всегда пишет ноль после считанных в буфер данных. Если мы вводим (с клавиатуры) больше символов, чем может поместиться в буфер, то (для Вашего случая `fgets(text, 12, stdin)`) в `text[]` будет помещено 11 байт, а в `text[11]` fgets() сама запишет 0.
Опасно, т.к. в рассмотренном случае `strlen(text)` вернет 11, и Вы запишите 0 в text[11 + 1], т.е. за последний байт, выделенный под массив.

Т.о., просто выбрасываем этот фрагмент за ненадобностью.

Теперь посмотрим на `search()`.

Да, идея просматривать не все, а только введенные символы в text[] -- абсолютно правильная
(использование той же переменной `c` в цикле по vocal[] -- очевидная ошибка, наверное описка).

Посмотрев на код чуть пристальней и подумав, а как может быть реализована функция strlen и при этом зная, что "строки" в Си это массивы байт, завершающиеся нулем,  можно прийти к выводу, что вызов strlen в этом контексте излишен. Мы же все равно будем перебирать символы text[], поэтому ничто не может нам помешать самим по ходу дела обнаружить конец строки.
Например, цикл по символам text[] может выглядеть так:

```
 for (j = 0; text[j]; j++)
```

Очевидно, что вложенный цикл по гласным можно (да и наверное, единообразный код это в самом деле хорошо) организовать так же, добавив нулевой байт в его конец
(кстати, тогда можно было бы описать гласные совсем просто:

```
static char vocal[] = "AEOYUI";
```

)

Но, для разнообразия технических приемов, мы пойдем другим путем и используем  переменную `c` (тут все начнут ругаться, что это плохое имя, имена переменных должны ... (это Вам расскажут все кому не лень)) для вычисления размера vocal[6] вот так:

```
с = sizeof(vocal) / sizeof(vocal[0]);
```

(Казалось бы -- дурь. Сами строчкой выше написали, что размер vocal 6! Но, в некоторых ситуациях лучше вычислять.)

Это стандартный прием для получения количества элементов массива. **Обратите внимание** истинный размер массива в этой точке должен быть известен компилятору (у нас внутри search() это справедливо для vocal[], *но не для text[] и result[]*, которые **реально создаются** (т.е. под них отводится память) в вызывающей функции).

Идем дальше и замечаем, что после того, как мы обнаружили, что text[i] гласная, перебирать оставшиеся гласные уже не нужно. В  результате основной код функции становится таким:

```
 с = sizeof(vocal) / sizeof(vocal[0]);
 for (i = 0; text[i]; i++)
   for (j = 0; j < c; j++)
     if (toupper(text[i]) == vocal[j]) {
       result[v++] = text[i]; // обычная сишная "красивость", совместим индексацию с изменением индекса в одном выражении
       break;   // в самом деле, раз нашли, так пойдем сразу дальше по text[]
     }
 result[v] = 0; // обязательно завершим список обнаруженных гласных 0
```

Должны ли тут мы вернуться в main, туда где отводили память под result[] и увеличить ее на 1?
(ответ -- нет, памяти как раз достаточно, поскольку такой же 0 обязательно заносится в text[] функцией fgets)

Теперь по поводу вопросов.

- Зачем возвращать длину result? Для красоты, законченности, расширения функционала, возможного упрощения использования search().  На самом деле Вы бесплатно получаете ответ на вопросы, а гласные есть? а сколько там гласных?

Тогда прототип станет таким:

```
int search (char text[], char result[]);
```

Ну, соответственно должна измениться и реализация:

```
int
search (char text[], char result[])
{
   ...
   return v;
}
```

Насчет возможного замечания насчет выбора типа функции `int` -- а не `size_t` я бы сказал -- давайте оставим пространство для маневра -- например, возможности возвращать ошибки (или сделать какое-то другое расширение функционала).

- Не понял про инициализирование 'text[12]' и 'result[12]'
  Не понял, что за код в цитате и что этот цикл делает, что за непонятные цифры "0x%02x" и словосочетание в начале аргументе (unsigned char)text[i].
  Не понял про '"bc\000aaaaaaaaa"'.

Речь об инициализации, насколько помню, шла в контексте кода в search()

```
for (i = 0; i < 12; i++)
   ...
   if (... text[i] ...
```

т.е. о доступе к потенциально неопределенным байтам. Думаю в свете всего вышеизложенного это стало неактуальным.

Код в цитате выводит шестнадцатеричные значения 12 первых байт массива text[] (для иллюстрации, что там может быть что угодно).  "0x%02x " -- этот формат говорит:

```
выведи пару символов `0` и `x`
выведи шестнадцатеричное значение (очередного) аргумента printf, который д.б. типа int
в случае одной цифры выведи лидирующий 0.
```

(А Вы почитайте [man 3 printf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf), да и потренируйтесь).

'"bc\000aaaaaaaaa"' -- очень просто (в книжке по Си где-то обязательно есть) при записи символьных строк (ими можно также инициализировать массивы (вроде бы я уже показывал это выше)) любой символ можно записать в виде -- бэкслеш и дальше 3 цифры его *восьмеричного кода*.

- с какой функции вводить строку? fgets, gets или scanf?

Вводить строку лучше функцией fgets(), поскольку она проверяет переполнение буфера.
При использовании GNU (gcc и соответствующая библиотека libc) также удобна функция getline() (почитайте [man getline](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getline), заодно освоите указатели). Как я понимаю, Вы используете винду, поэтому самостоятельная реализация getline (надеюсь, в недалеком будущем) м.б. отличным упражнением (а заодно и тестом на освоение Си)).